# WCF Basichttpbinding web.config example for REST API

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-config, basichttpbinding

I tried to find web.config for my WCF service connect to server using REST call. However, its saying unable to connect server. Here is my web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <!--<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>-->
<appSettings>
<add key="UserName" value="admin"/>
<add key="Password" value="admin"/>
<add key="resturl" value="https://Clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/"/>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IJiraService"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
   <client>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:19065/JiraService.svc"  binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IJiraService" contract="ServiceReference1.IJiraService"
       name="BasicHttpBinding_IJiraService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior>
         <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
       </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
   </protocolMapping>    
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Could anyone please help me, how can I correct this? I tried on net, however, not able to find any suitable tutorial for this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. Its was a proxy issue and after adding proxy to browser and IIS the issue got resolved. Thanks.